# Can git make a guess at what's the merge base when doing a subtree merge and there are no common ancestors?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to get my mind around the subtree merge. Let's we need to use one project as a subtree in another one and then have an opportunity to update the first through fetching instruments (and vice versa). Our workflow would be something like that:

```
$ git init subtree-project
$ cd subtree-project
$ echo foo > foo.TXT
$ git add .
$ git commit -m v1
$ cd ..
$ git init main-project 
$ cd main-project
$ echo boo > boo.TXT
$ git add .
$ git commit -m v1
$ git remote add subtree ../subtree-project
$ git fetch subtree
$ git branch subtree-project-master subtree/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=subtree-directory -u subtree-project-master
$ git commit -am v2 #save a subtree in the master branch
```

Then the `subtree-project` was updated (`v2`). After pulling a new commit into the `subtree-project-master` branch, I merge it as a subtree (`subtree-directory`) into the `master` branch:

```
$ git merge --squash -s recursive -Xsubtree=subtree-directory subtree-project-master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Why does git need the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag here? After all, we use a subtree merge and is it not enough for git to silently fulfill fast-forward merging?

Just for clarification of my question: as far as I understand the concept of subtree merge, git in this case can take a guess at what can be regarded as base blob objects for being merged ones. That is, if the `main-project` borrowed a tree object (and related blob objects) from `subtree-project` (its `v1` state) through the `read-tree` command, then git can consider that blob objects to be the base for 3-diffing.

I'm almost certain it's a misunderstanding but still need some clarification.

Comment: The short answer is no, Git does not make any such guess. The information was never recorded anywhere either. If you save it manually, it's theoretically possible to provide it (equally manually) but there's no front end setup for this. The -X option here just helps with tree-shape-matching. There is a (different) workflow you could use where it would all just work, though. Essentially you'd maintain separate branches: one without the read-tree action, and one with. You'd then merge each part separately and use read-tree to build the final combined versions.

Comment: This would still require a lot of manual fiddling, but you could script all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does git need the --allow-unrelated-histories flag here?

Because, so far as git can tell, the histories are unrelated. Your original insertion wasn't recorded as a merge, it was done with a no-ancestry read-tree.

Instead, record the merge,

```
git fetch subtree
# do the first one as a handroll to show git where things go
git merge -s ours --no-commit subtree/master --allow-unrelated-histories
git read-tree -u --prefix=subtree-directory
git commit
```

and now that git sees what you're doing, you can tell it to do it again:

```
[... time passes, subtree project changes ...]
git fetch subtree
git merge -s subtree subtree/master
```